# visual C#. Validar datos insertados en textbox

Tags: c#, validación

busco la forma de validar datos entrados a un textbox el cual se utiliza para obtener el valor entrado y llevarlo a formulas matematicas. Ya cree una funcion la cual el usuario solo puede entrar numeros(0-9), y los caracteres ".", "," y "-" para escribir decimales y negativos, pero mi problema es :
cuando el usuario entra algo como :  "..-", ",.,", "-." el programa da error. Podrian ayudarme? gracias de antemano.
les dejo la funcion para validar como la tengo hasta este minuto

```
public static void SoloNumeros(KeyPressEventArgs V)


{
            if (Char.IsDigit(V.KeyChar))
            {
                V.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsControl(V.KeyChar))
            {

                V.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsControl(V.KeyChar))
            {
                V.Handled = false;            
            }
            else if (V.KeyChar.ToString().Equals("."))
            {

                V.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (V.KeyChar.ToString().Equals(","))
            {

                V.Handled = false;
            }

            else if (V.KeyChar.ToString().Equals("-"))
            {

                V.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                V.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor, introduzca solo nùmeros.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el metodo Tryparse. en tu caso el metodo de bool (por que double acepta es capas de parsear ".")

seria algo asi :

```
 int numero;
 bool esNumerico = bool.TryParse(TextBox.ToString(), out numero);

 if(esNumerico == false)
 {
        V.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, introduzca solo nùmeros.");
 }
```

Tryparse es una funcion que intentara convertir el primer parametro string en un numero.

si Tryparse es exitoso, el parametro out sera cargado con el valor de la conversion y el resultado de la funcion sera "true"

pero si Tryparse falla, el parametro out quedara nullo y el resultado de la funcion sera false

Ahora veo otro problema, y es que estas tratando de validar caracter por caracter,

no podras hacer esto de ninguna manera para averiguar si tu resultado es numerico o no, preferible que hagas un tryparse en el con todo el texto del textbox y no de caracter por caracter.

Comment: Creo que hay un error en el signo de igual en lugar de guion en bool esNumerico = Int32.TryParse....

Comment: Sugiero que pongas la declaración del evento OnChange para que sea mas claro el ejemplo

Comment: @AlejandroMedina encontre un error en mi logica, esta bien hacerlo en el keypress pero lo importante es validar el texto entero, y mas importante que sea bool para poder aceptar comas y puntos

Comment: Yo uso Regex en lugar de validar de esa forma, checa esta página  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13255/Validation-with-Regular-Expressions-Made-Simple

Answer (score 0):

realice el siguiente código que te puede ayudar con tu cuestión, para tu metodo estatico de SoloNumeros realice el siguiente código la cual simplifica mas tu código

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^*[0-9,\.\-]+$");
        if (regex.IsMatch(V.KeyChar.ToString()) || V.KeyChar.ToString() == "\b")
        {
            V.Handled = false;

        }
        else
        {
            V.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor, introduzca solo nùmeros.");
        }
```

Para evitar que el numero este erróneo al momento de realizar la operación y evitar que pase por el código un numero con las siguientes características 3..4 realice el siguiente código.

```
     public bool validarNumeroAntesDeOperacion(string numero)
     {
        bool EsValido;
        try
        {
            double Numero = Convert.ToDouble(numero);
            EsValido = true;
        }
     catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            EsValido = false;
        }

        return EsValido;
        }
```

Este código regresa un true o un false si el numero es correcto o incorrecto, en tu caso utiliza un double que ayudara mucho, si lo que buscas en hacerlo en tiempo real te recomiendo realizar un expresion regex que te permita validar que no se repitan los caracteres.

Answer (score 0):

Mike , muchas gracias por tu respuesta , no conocia el metodo double.TryParse, me fue de gran ayuda, ya encontre la solucion a mi problema
cree el sgte metodo:

//Class Validar

```
public bool validacion2(string value ) 
    {
        bool esNumerico= false;
        double numero;
        if(Double.TryParse(value ,  out numero))
        {
        esNumerico=true;            
        }
        return esNumerico;           
    }
```

este metodo lo use en elevento clic de un boton "Calcular" q tengo en mi programa. quedo algo mas menos asi

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Validar a1 = new Validar();
     if ((a1.validacion2(textBox1.Text) == false)
         MessageBox.Show("Existen valores no coherentes. Por favor, revise los datos insertados.");
     else
     {
        //continua el programa 
     }
}
```